# Move file to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have following code:

```
var sourceSite = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/afd-286-oprydning-test-source";
var targetSIte = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/afd-286-oprydning-test-target";

var ctx = ClientContextExtension.GetAppContext(sourceSite, _config.AppRegistrationId, _config.AppRegistrationKey, "SaveToExcel", new EmptyLogger());
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = ctx.Web.GetDocumentsList();
 var item = list.GetItemById(1);
 ctx.Load(item);
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();

 if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
 {
     var file = item.File;
     ctx.Load(file);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     var r = new ResourcePath();

     file.MoveTo("/sites/afd-286-oprydning-test-target/TestDoc/Test01.docx", Movperations.Overwrite);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

I get following error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Server relative urls
>   must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl'

Any pointers how to move a file? I also tried a fully qualified url but no luck.

According to documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt780894(v%3Doffice.15)

You should use MoveToByPath but I havent found a single hit on a sample on google.

Comment: Can you try to remove trailing slash in `file.MoveTo`: `file.MoveTo("sites/afd-286-oprydning-test-target/TestDoc/Test01.docx", Movperations.Overwrite);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others. It is actually possible with multiple different approaches. There is a CopyUtil in CSOM but also this one. Tested and works.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt796381(v%3Doffice.15)

Comment: If you add some sample code it will be helpful for the community, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can not move file using file.MoveTo method from one site to another site. There is no built-in method in SharePoint CSOM for moving Files from one site into another.

But you can use below procedure to move file.

```
public static void FileMove(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string srcLibrary, string destLibrary, string srcFileName)
{
    ClientContext srcContext = new ClientContext(srcUrl);
    ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);            

    Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
    srcContext.Load(srcWeb);            
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
    destContext.Load(destWeb);
    destContext.ExecuteQuery();

    try
    {
        var fileRelativePath = (srcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.EndsWith("/") ? srcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl : srcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/") + "Lists/" + srcLibrary + "/" + srcFileName;
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = srcWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileRelativePath);
        srcContext.Load(file);
        srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

        string location = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/Lists/" + destLibrary + "/" + file.Name;
        FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, location, fileInfo.Stream, true);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Call this method with following parameters

```
var srcUrl = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/SourceSite/";
var destUrl = "https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/TargetSite/";
var srcLibrary = "Documents";
var destLibrary = "Documents";
var srcFileName = "Test.docx";

FileMove(srcUrl, destUrl, srcLibrary, destLibrary, srcFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I feared:( Would have been so nice to only have a single operation due to throttles, where a pointer is just moved on the backend. I will use your approach, thanks alot.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark this as correct answer and give vote.

Comment: I just tested the code. Unfortuneantly it does not work with modern authentication and app registrations:( I get an 401.

Comment: May be you want to add authentication for the context. See this code for authentication:

string userName = "YourUserName";           
string password = "YourPssword";
SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
{
 securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

srcContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
srcContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: I am using an app registration. It is a big enterprise customer. However I found another approach. The problem was the customer is using modern authentication. SaveBinaryDirect does not work with modern authentication.

Comment: Ok, I got it, Glad to know that you are able to resolve the problem.